# Knockout Binding on Modified Element

Tags: knockout.js

In my current project in some cases I need to change the position, sorting of some elements which knockout bindings are applied. I am using jQuery to change the position or modify these elements. But this modifications removes the binding's from these elements that I modify.

I am including the basic example of to demonstrate the problem by modifying the first example from knokocutjs.com

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {

this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));

    $('#test').click(function(){

    var firstName = $('body').find('p:eq(0)');
    $('body').find('p:eq(0)').remove();
    $(firstName).insertBefore($('body').find('p:eq(0)'));

});
```

});

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamet/3sSgd/3/)!

Comment: What do you want exactly? what is your expected result? what should be done on the button's click?

Comment: Don't use jQuery for this. Stick to the MVVM style of Knockout and have things like "position" emerge from your VM and have the View reflect that. Rely on Knockout to update the view (in this case: sorting parts of it) when you change the view model.

Comment: At My actual approach I have a grid that I populate add remove columns add rows etc using knockout every thing is fine. But I need to add drag drop columns and for this approach I am using jebairds drag drop columns plugin. This plugin changes the columns position by swaping them and this ruins my knockout bindings. I couldnt include the actual sample because it's all db driven